# Way to accept different clousure in inits and assign it to the same private variable

Tags: swift, closures

Suppose I have two inits and one private property like below.

```
struct MyStruct {
    let clousure: (Int, String, Bool) -> String
    
    public init(clousure: @escaping (Int, String) -> String) {
        /// How to assign this to the private property of MyStruct
        self.clousure = ... ? /// THIS IS MY QUESTION
    }

    public init(clousure: @escaping (Int, String, Bool) -> String, ... ) {...}
```

Is there a way how can i wrap the accepted clousure and supply the bool as some default value, i.e false?
thanks in advance

Comment: Could you restructure it to only have one `init` method that is **variadic**?  That means a function that can accept an unknown number of arguments in array form, where the array can be empty.  That would allow you to call the closure function with either 2 or 3 arguments (with or without the boolean).  I'm assuming that's what you're trying to do.  Here is an example you can run in a Swift playground (replace all the pipe `|` characters with newlines):

Comment: `import Foundation`|`struct MyStruct {`|`let closure: (Int, String, Bool...) -> String`|`public init(closure: @escaping (Int, String, Bool...) -> String) {`|`self.closure = closure`|`}`|`}`|`let struct1 = MyStruct() { number, name, hasCake in`|`var result = "\(name) will turn \(number) tomorrow."`|`if !hasCake.isEmpty && hasCake[0] {`|`result += "  \(name) is having cake!"`|`} else {`|`result += "  \(name) is not having cake."`|`}`|`return result`|`}`|`struct1.closure(2, "Bob", false)`|`struct1.closure(200, "Bob", true)`|`struct1.closure(50, "Bob")`

Comment: The example calls the closure function (from the private property) 3 times:  once with the boolean argument `true`, once with it `false`, and once without it.  The case where the boolean is not provided acts the same as the one where the boolean was false.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but might be a possible workaround.  Here is my source for variadic functions in Swift (I learned something new today too: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/variadic-parameters/).  Of course this is for Swift 5, not sure whether everything will be compatible with Swift 3 or not.  +1 for a great question and Following to see if anyone can answer as you intended

Comment: @QuackE.Duck in a way it accomplishes what i want, but I would prefer to have to inits like above. But if no one will suggest anything else, I am going to take your solutions :D. Thanks again buddy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would share more info about the goal and what you are trying to achieve by passing the clousure and/or disregard part of the arguments we can help further. From the code point of view, it seems like the @escaping closure you are passing can just disregard the boolean value as follow:

```
struct MyStruct {
  let clousure: (Int, String, Bool) -> String

  public init(clousure: @escaping (Int, String) -> String) {
      /// How to assign this to the private property of MyStruct
      self.clousure = { i, str, _ -> String in
          return clousure(i, str)
      }
  }
}
```

And be used as follow:

```
let s = MyStruct() { i, s -> String in return "string = \(s), int = \(i)"}
print(s.clousure(1, "hello", false))
```

Resulting in the output

```
    string = hello, int = 1
```

I'm not sure why would you want to do that, maybe you indeed want to achieve something like @Quack E. Duck suggested and have different outcome given the boolean value:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let clousure: (Int, String, Bool) -> String

    public init(clousure: @escaping (Int, String) -> String) {
        /// How to assign this to the private property of MyStruct
        self.clousure = { i, str, increaseCount -> String in
            if increaseCount { return clousure(i+1, str) }
            else { return clousure(i, str) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot, "can just disregard the boolean value as follow:" this is what i have wanted.